# Highlight cells with different values than present in the column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to go through a table (X by Y) where every column (X) should have the same value (string) and would like the cell to get highlighted if is not the same value. I'm stuck in building the comparison method, because I would like it to be dynamic. I would like to first determine what is the value that is present the most in the column and determine that is what everything else needs to be compared against and highlight the cell that is not equal to this value.

Example (6x5 table) -

> A 3 4 C M R
>
> A 3 4 O M R
>
> 8 3 T O M F
>
> 8 3 4 O M G
>
> A 3 T O Y K

In the first column, A is the most prevalent value therefore the (8s) are highlighted, second column nothing is highlighted, third both (T) are highlighted, fourth column (C), fifth column (Y) and sixth column (F),(G) and (K) are highlighted.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution, I've commented the code so you can understand

```
    Sub HighlightNonFrequentInColumn()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim col As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim myVal As String
    Dim colRng As String

    Set rng = Selection '<<change range as required

    For Each col In rng.Columns
        'determine the most frequent value
        colRng = col.Address
        On Error Resume Next
        myVal = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(" & colRng & ",MODE(IF(" & colRng & "<>"""",MATCH(" & colRng & "," & colRng & ",0))))")
        If Application.countblanks(col) > Application.CountIf(col, myVal) Then myVal = "" '<<if blanks are most frequent
        'highlight all cells not equals to most frequent value
        For Each cell In col.Cells
            If Not cell = myVal Then cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow '<<change colour as desired
        Next
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but what if one of the columns is completely blank? It seems it won't work. If the majority of the column is Blank then everything else would have to be compared against Blank and flag what is not Blank.

Comment: I've updated the code above to take into account blanks. Note, if more than 1 value has a max frequency in a column then it will only select one as the most frequent and highlight all the others

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a workaround. Not sure if this is the best way though.

[image]

Step 1. Create a count if table which basically gives you the count of a value in the column. Ex: for cell F4 use formula =COUNTIF($B$4:$B$8,B4)

Step 2. Create a row with max values of each column. Ex: Cell F11 =MAX(F4:F8)

Step 3. For each cell, give a conditional formatting condition that if the value in the count table does not match the max value, color it. Ex: for cell B4, go to conditional formatting -> new rule -> use a formula and write this formula =F4<>F$11. Then copy paste the format to all other cells.

Note: this will not work when multiple values in a column have the same max count.